# WordPress site stops loading – Maximum execution time exceeded in wp-db.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, offline

From Last one month I am facing issue with WordPress website. The website stops loading.
Sometimes it goes back online automatically. Usually from minutes to an hour. If I am online and it hasn’t gone online in an hour I restart  MySQL which typically resolves the issue.

I have already performed following steps but nothing seems to work.

1. Increased execution time to 600 in wp-config.php
2. Increased the available space in C drive.
3. Repaired the database.
4. Updated WordPress and plugins

Still the site goes down.
Currently the error that gets logged in phperrors.log file is

Maximum execution time of 600 seconds exceeded in -\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1944

Please let me know what steps should I take to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert in WP but maybe others including myself could help if we knew whats in `wp-db.php on line 1944`

Comment: @Radha - Please check with hosting provider after you can try to follow the steps. Because may be issue with hosting.